# dropdown values

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have the below code that display list of values from database in drop down. The query also selects Jt_JOB_Description. I would like to display the Jt_JOB_Description based on the JT_JOB_TITLE selected in Text Area. Help plz.

```
<select  name="jTitle" id="jTitle" style="background-color: #D8D8D8">
<%

Statement stt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rstt = stt.executeQuery("SELECT JT_JOB_TITLE, JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION FROM     uap.dbo.UAP_JOB_TITLE ORDER BY JT_JOB_TITLE");
 while (rstt.next()) { 
%>
 <option value="<%=rstt.getString("JT_JOB_TITLE")%>">        <%=rstt.getString("JT_JOB_TITLE")%>
 </option>
<%
 }
 stt.close();
 rstt.close();
 %>
 </select>

   <textarea class="styled" rows="5" cols="12" name="jDesc" id="jDesc" ></textarea>
```

Comment: On selection of dropdown box you have to submit page again Which will fire query for that and get description or another way is use javascript simply for that.

Comment: How to use Javascript in this case. I would not like to submit the form. Because JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION includes all the values from database.

Comment: Please do not put JDBC code in your JSPs: [Why JSP + JDBC is bad](http://www.selikoff.net/2009/02/24/why-jdbc-jsp-bad/). Ceterum censeo...

Comment: It is recommended to avoid script let tags on JSP. But you are using JDBC code.Please do not you such codes on JSP page.

Comment: Do you need , when you select any title the subsequent Description will visible on TextArea.

Comment: Yes, that's correct JDeveloper. Also let me know how to put the JDBC code in another file for drop downs. if this helps me to improve the performance

Comment: @f_Puras...  could you let me know how to differenciate JDBC and JSP code in cases like my issue. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as given below

```
<select  name="jTitle" id="jTitle" style="background-color: #D8D8D8" onchange="setText(this)">
<%
String str=""; 
Statement stt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rstt = stt.executeQuery("SELECT JT_JOB_TITLE, JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION FROM uap.dbo.UAP_JOB_TITLE ORDER BY JT_JOB_TITLE");
while (rstt.next()) { 
str+=rstt.getString(1)+"@"+rstt.getString(2)+"#"; 
%>
<option value="<%=rstt.getString("JT_JOB_TITLE")%>"><%=rstt.getString("JT_JOB_TITLE")%>
</option>
<%
}
stt.close();
rstt.close();
%>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="txtHidStr" id="txtHidStr" value="<%=str %>" /> 

<textarea class="styled" rows="5" cols="12" name="jDesc" id="jDesc" ></textarea>
```

and wirte following javascript function

```
function setText(element){
var arr_main=document.getElementById("txtHidStr").value.split("#");
for(i=0;i<arr_main.length;i++)
{
     arr_val=arr_main[i].split("@");
     if(arr_val[0]==element.value)
     {
        document.getElementById("jDesc").innerHTML=arr_val[1];
        break;
     }
}
}
```